# Is freeze ray possible?

Tags: internal-consistency, weapons, energy, climate-change

Set in distant future in order to reverse global warming caused by the depletion of ozone layer, the world no longer release CFC gases into the atmosphere and also vows to repair ice cap in Antarctica. A freeze ray is using either laser or stream of particles to rob the energy of the targeted object in order to greatly reduce the kinetic energy of atoms and molecules in a moment, is such device possible? or do I book an one way ticket to Mars instead?

Comment: Depletion of ozone layer (which has almost fully recovered) is **not** causing Global Warming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with a freeze ray is the energy transfer.  Most 'rays' are sending something, particles, light, some imaginary force.  When you 'add' to something you are generally adding energy to it and often as heat.  A freeze ray needs to 'suck the heat out'.

So to make a freeze ray you can try a catalyst that will make something give up it's heat, say making water freeze at a warmer temperature than normal (this of course would have the problem of 'releasing' all that stored energy into the atmosphere, so while the water would freeze, it would actually warm up the planet first.

The other way in general is heat transfer from a warm body to a cold one, the large the difference in heat the faster the transfer.  So if the freeze ray was sending large amounts of matter that was near absolute zero, as the matter mixed with the target, the heat transfer would be fast.  Like dropping a banana into liquid nitrogen.

It is much easier to add heat quickly than take it away...

One other thought occurred to me.  if you find a chemical or physical reaction that absorbs heat/energy leaving less in the end, maybe something that turns energy into mass...?

Comment: keep in mind the different means of heat transfer. If you're trying to freeze a solid object you're pretty much relying on conduction only meaning that the cold temperature can only penetrate towards the core of the object by reducing the temperature of the outer layers, making heat transfer rates and distance limiting factors.

Answer (score 2):

There is this thing called [laser cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_cooling) - if you have a simple enough material (like pure helium) and exactly the right kind of laser, you can use the laser to cool the material. Getting it to work with compounds or large amounts of matter (meaning grams) is finicky, but I guess that is as close as we can get to a freeze-ray.

Answer (score 1):

A jet of liquid nitrogen is a sort of freeze ray.  The wearer would have a pressurized tank on their back.  The liquid is dispensed like a flamethrower.  This is guaranteed to reduce heat energy of the target.  The nitrogen evaporates into the atmosphere pretty soon.

I don't see any way that could prevent global warming, though. It is far to expensive to think about freezing a continent of glaciers that way.  For that, maybe you can mass produce reactants for an endothermic reaction.
Anything that causes that amount of freezing is going to be in the realm of science-fiction.

Answer (score 0):

Endothermic reactions can absorb heat with some cooling bellow 0c/freezing,so you could potentially have a freeze gun using this effect.

Regarding an energy weapon/ray that freezes
small amounts of heat can be transferred through radiation so having a near zero degree kelvin surface faceing the target  would absobe infrared but would not emit it effectively acting as a very under powered freeze ray.

Another option is useing a lazzer to confine parasitical s stopping them from moving but that's currently difficult on large scales.

Another possible thought if you compress a gas then release it it will transfer some of it's energy as it expands and cool down.
If you could find a way to compress a gas from a distance then release it it would heat up as you compress it then could  cool down bellow it's initial temperature.
finding a way to compressing air from a distance would be hard though.